# C# WPF ellipse bouncing on rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a solo pong game for a school project, but I don't know how to handle the ellipse bouncing on the rectangle. They're both inside a canvas as you can see in the XAML, I'll leave my code, please I need help, because I'm stuck at this point.
I tried different ways, but I can't figure it out, so any tip will be helpful!

```
<Window x:Class="PongSolo.Game"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PongSolo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Game" Height="450" Width="650" Closing="Game_Closing" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Name="superBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10" Grid.Row="1">
            <Canvas Name="superCanvas">
                <Rectangle x:Name="superRect" Fill="Blue" Width="100" Height="15" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="0"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="superElly" Fill="Purple" Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
        <Label Content="Punteggio:" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label Content="0" Name="scoreLabel" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" Margin="119,0,-119,0"/>
       
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Media;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace PongSolo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per Game.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Game : Window
    {
        SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Environment.CurrentDirectory+"/Resources/bgm_new.wav");
        DispatcherTimer playerDispatcher = new DispatcherTimer();
        DispatcherTimer ballDispatcher = new DispatcherTimer();

        int score = 0;

        double startxspeed = 4;
        double startyspeed = 4;
        public Game()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            playerDispatcher.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
            ballDispatcher.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
            ballDispatcher.Tick += ballMovement;
            playerDispatcher.Tick += playerMovement;
            playerDispatcher.Start();
            ballDispatcher.Start();
        }

        private void ballMovement(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double xspeed = Canvas.GetLeft(superElly) + startxspeed;
            double yspeed = Canvas.GetTop(superElly) + startyspeed;
        
               //Ball collision with rectangle
                if(/*bouncing statement*/)
                {
                    score++;
                    scoreLabel.Content = score.ToString();
                    startyspeed *= -1;
                }


            //up collision
            if (yspeed < (superCanvas.ActualHeight - (superElly.ActualHeight / 2)) && yspeed > 0)
                Canvas.SetTop(superElly, yspeed);
            else
            {
                startyspeed *= -1;
            }
                

            //down collision
            if(yspeed >= (superCanvas.ActualHeight - (superElly.ActualHeight/2)) && yspeed >0)
            {
                playerDispatcher.Stop();
                ballDispatcher.Stop();
            }

            //lateral collision
            if (xspeed < (superCanvas.ActualWidth - (superElly.ActualWidth / 2 + 10)) && xspeed > 0)
                Canvas.SetLeft(superElly, xspeed);
            else
            {
                startxspeed *= -1;
            }
               
        }

        private void playerMovement(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double xvalue = Canvas.GetLeft(superRect) + 3;

            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Left))
            {
                if (!outOfBoundaries("left"))
                    MovePlayerLeft();
            }              
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Right))
            {
                if (!outOfBoundaries("right"))
                    MovePlayerRight();
            }                   
        }

        public bool outOfBoundaries(string s)
        {
            bool is_out_of_boundaries = false;
            switch (s)
            {
                case "left":
                    {
                        if (Canvas.GetLeft(superRect) <= 0)
                            is_out_of_boundaries = true;
                        break;
                    }                 
                case "right":
                    {
                        if (Canvas.GetLeft(superRect) >= superCanvas.ActualWidth-superRect.Width)
                            is_out_of_boundaries = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return is_out_of_boundaries;
        }

        private void MovePlayerRight()
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(superRect, Canvas.GetLeft(superRect) + 5);
        }

        private void MovePlayerLeft()
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(superRect, Canvas.GetLeft(superRect) - 5);
        }

        private void Game_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.MinHeight = 300;
            this.MinWidth = 300;
            PlayMusic();
        }

        private void PlayMusic()
        {   
            sound.PlayLooping();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to break this problem into pieces. First you'll need the involved objects positioning and speed. Then you'll need some collision detection. After that you'll be able to apply physics to alter the velocity of the objects involved. Btw; I believe Unity3D has a lot of these features out of the box.

Comment: I only have the possibility to use Visual Studio, I'm not able to use Unity

Comment: Ok, then, still: I do believe you should start with breaking down the problem in pieces and ask about the first issue you encounter. As it is now, it's quite hard to answer - possible, but not easy.

Comment: actually that's my only problem because I don't know what to do

Comment: As I said; start with the movement: First you'll need the involved objects positioning and speed. Then you'll need some collision detection. After that you'll be able to apply physics to alter the velocity of the objects involved.

Comment: So I think it's best to start a new question, focusing on the issue you experience while trying to determine velocity